# Hibernet SubQuery problem using in springboot java

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

here is my query
SELECT DISTINCT c FROM Candidate c INNER JOIN (SELECT ja from JobApplication ja INNER JOIN Job j ON ja.jId=j.id where j.companyId = 364) as fillterappli ON fillterappli.caId=c.id

here is the Error:
14:18:37.706 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] ERROR o.h.hql.internal.ast.ErrorTracker - line 1:75: unexpected token: (

Comment: Your query is native SQL.  Are you running it as an HQL query?

Comment: Running as a HQL